# Ruby on Rails cannot load such file -- maxminddb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the [MaxMindDB](https://github.com/yhirose/maxminddb) gem to use thew new MaxMind v2 geoip database.

I've added the gem to my gemfile and installed it. But when I try to require it in a class or in the console I get a `cannot load such file -- maxminddb` error:

```
2.3.1 :004 > require 'maxminddb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- maxminddb
```

It looks like the code itself is wrapped in a `MaxMindDB` module. Really I want to get to the point of doing:

```
db = MaxMindDB.new('geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
ret = db.lookup('74.125.225.224')
```

Right now I get an uninitialized constant error:

```
db = MaxMindDB.new('geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
NameError: uninitialized constant MaxMindDB
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? It seems like the gem should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have this file : `GeoLite2-City.mmdb`

You need to get the file and that's how you initialise the db using :

`db = MaxMindDB.new('geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')`

You can download the db file here : http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/#Databases

Comment: I have the file downloaded in the geoip folder. The problem is that `MaxMindDB` is not found as a class

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the gem?

Comment: every rails developer would have had this day :)